# Django 1.7 с двумя версиями python как заставить работать?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

У меня Ubuntu 14.04

```
python -V 
Python 2.7.6

python3 -V
Python 3.4.3
```

Django 1.8.7 (Устанавливал через pip)

Из под python видно django
Из под python3 не видно

Как заставить django работать с python3?

Comment: нужно устанавливать Django в виртуальное окружение virtualenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае можно использовать [виртуальное окружение](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
user@server: pip install virtualenv
user@server: virtualenv -p /path/to/python3.3 myenv
user@server: source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv)user@server: pip install django
```

Во второй строчке говорится, что в виртуальном окружении надо использовать `python3.3`.